# Restricting api access by client

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, openid, identityserver4

I have an identity server built with Identity server 4.    There is one main API with several angular web applications build by third party customers that access this API endpoint.

Now I would like to create a second API but its only for internal use with **OUR** official plugin.  I am trying to figure out how to lock it down so that only our app can access it. I am not a fan security by obscurity and assuming that the third party's dont know its there so wont try and access it.

My first thought was to add a new scope for this API but by doing that its going to popup and ask the users for access to the data which isnt really need.

The only thing i can think of would be to check the client id some how in the API and add a policy for it. This really isnt right ether as to my understanding polciy should be checking stats of the user and not the client itself.

```
services.AddAuthorization(
    options => {
        options.AddPolicy("DevConsole", policy => IsClientId(xxxx)
    }
);
```

Is it possible to lock down an API based upon a single client id?  or am i going at this in the wrong way.

Another idea i had was to add another claim if they login with this client id which seams like overkill to me.

**Example:**

Lets say that I have an API endpoint that allows you to update the usersname.   All users have access to their name this isnt a scope issue.  However only our official app has access to update the usersname.   Any app created by third party developers do not have access to the endpoint to update a usersname.

So our official plugin has a client id of 123 and yours has a client id of 321.  A user logged though client id 321 can not access this endpoint.  User logged in though client id 123 can.

I am starting to think this isnt possible because Oauth and Openid are completely user based.  There is no way to validate the user based upon the client they authenticated with.

Comment: What do you mean by _"... ask the users for access to the data which isnt really need"_? I think users of your official plugin would just have to approve (on the consent page) delegation of the new scope rights to the plugin. Is it a problem or why isn't it needed?

Comment: Anyone that logs in has access to this data.   Its the Client that the user is logged in with that that may or may not have access to request the data.    Scope is user based it requests access of the users data everyone has access to this data.   But if you create an app and i give you a client id you do not have access to use this api.

Comment: @JánHalaša check my update i added an example of what i am trying to do.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly concerns you about the scope. I got this with the access, but it has nothing to do with the API allowance. The common API's can read the data, but only yours can edit it. And only a client, having your scope can access your API. Am I missing something?

Comment: The main issue is than management don't want to display an additional scope to the users.  because it will force everyone to concent and that it's in there opinion silly to have a second scope when the data is already accessable in the first

Answer (score 0):

if I understand the problem correctly, I would create a new Client on Identity Server, for the "main API" and a new Resource for the "internal API"

This would allow the "main API" to also be a client, with client credentials grant type, therefore it has a id+secret and is allowed to request a token for itself. In this case, you will now request the newly created scope for in "internal API" and the users will have no knowledge that this entity evens exists.

Answer (score 0):

After going back and forth with this with this it occurred to me that the client id is returned as a claim.   So when i got in this morning i checked.

This should enable me to add a policy for only our official plugin.

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("IsOfficalApp", policy => IsCheckOfficalClient());
            });
```

This should enable me to lock down the API endpoints in question without requiring additional authorization from the users.